# How do plot several variables along the x axis with their values along the y axis

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a list of variables on R, each with their own numerical value. How can I set those variables so that I can plot a bar chart, whereby the variables are named along the x-axis

Example:

```
my_list <- list(a, b, c, d, e, f, g)
```

where a to g are all variables with numerical values

```
frame2 <- data.frame(my_list)
ggplot(data=frame2, aes(x=my_list, y=Total))+
   geom_col()
```

Ideally, a bar chart with a to g along the x axis would appear but templates I've used so far don't work.
Should I stop using a list altogether?

Comment: Have your tried `data.frame(a, b, c, d, e, f, g)`?

Answer (score 1):

Using some random example data. From your description I simply guessed that your vars contain only one(?) total value. Nevertheless in either case the trick is to convert the dataframe into long format via e.g. `tidyr::pivot_longer`. This way your vars can be treated as different categories of one variable which we plot on the x-axis. Try this

```r
set.seed(42)
my_list <- list(a = runif(1), b = runif(1), c = runif(1))

frame2 <- data.frame(my_list)

library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

frame2 %>% 
  tidyr::pivot_longer(everything(), names_to = "var", values_to = "Total") %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=var, y = Total, fill=var))+
  geom_col(position = "dodge")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-04-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

It is not really clear what `Total` is in your ggplot syntax.

Generally I would indeed not use a list, but go about it like so

```
my_df <- data.frame(vars = letters[1:7], value = 1:7)

ggplot(my_df, aes(x = vars, y = value)) + geom_col()
```